# Variable declaration syntax

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb, recordset

Basically I follow a spec to create functions in Access 2010.  These functions are in VBA.  When working with record sets the given declaration in the spec is

```
Dim obj.Recordset As New ADODB.Recordset
```

Yet every time I try and write it I get a syntax error so I just use:

```
Dim Recordset As object
```

I am not sure if this means the same thing but it compiles and seems to work fine.  Basically my question is, is the given declaration for a recordset correct and is my alternative acceptable.  Also Access 2010 is used as a user front end and the database is stored in MS- SQL server 2008 backend.

Comment: what "spec" do you follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to define a variable with a '.' in the variable name. That is not a valid character in a variable name. If I didn't know better, this syntax looks like you are trying to somehow assign a data type of ADODB.Recordset to a property named 'Recordset' of a class object named 'obj' (which would be extremely bizarre and I don't know of a valid syntax for in VBA or why anyone would want to). I would expect the following will compile:

```
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
```

Also make sure you have added the appropriate reference in Tools --> References (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library or other latest version). As to your second question, that should be a viable alternative but I prefer the strongly typed former.

Comment: ++ but *`define the type of an parameter of object 'obj'.`* probably needs to be clarified a bit ;)

Comment: @mehow Is that clearer? My point is that in the context of VBA the alternative reading of the syntax doesn't make much if any sense.

Comment: Oh okay so yes once I removed the period it compiled, perhaps the spec had a typo. thank you